# Vanilla JS - slider - Active dots

Tags: javascript

Please, can you help me assign .active class to slider Dots, which are generated by JS, they are not part of HTML. When slide 1 is active, I need dot 1 to have class .active, but no luck.. all solutions I have foud are for dots hardcoded in HTML.

My HTML:

```
  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
        <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
            <h3>Slide 1</h3>
            <p>1. Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
        <div class="w3-display-bottomright w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
            <h3>Slide 2</h3>
            <p>2.Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
            <h3>Slide 3</h3>
            <p>3. Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <div id="js-slider-dots"></div>
    <button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
```

My JS (which switch the slides and generate dots):

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function goToDiv(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function generateDots() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var dotNumber = i + 1;
        var dot = document.createElement('span');
        dot.innerHTML =
            '<button class="js-dot" onclick="goToDiv(' + dotNumber + ')">' + dotNumber + '</button>';

        document.getElementById('js-slider-dots').appendChild(dot);

    }
}
generateDots();
```

It is also all live on JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/ketohatane/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it by `.classList.add()` and `.remove()`.

Just select the dots, and *activate* the dot that belongs to the active slide at `showDivs`:

```js
function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    //get the list of dots
    var y = document.getElementById("js-slider-dots").children;
    if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
        //remove .active from all dots
        y[i].classList.remove("active")
    }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    //add .active to the selected dot
    y[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active")
}
```

See this snippet:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;

function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function goToDiv(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
//get the list of dots
var y = document.getElementById("js-slider-dots").children;
if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
    //remove .active from all dots
    y[i].classList.remove("active")
}
x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
//add .active to the selected dot
y[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active")
}

function generateDots() {
 var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var dotNumber = i + 1;
  var dot = document.createElement('span');
  dot.innerHTML =
   '<button class="js-dot" onclick="goToDiv(' + dotNumber + ')">' + dotNumber + '</button>';

  document.getElementById('js-slider-dots').appendChild(dot);

 }
}
generateDots();
//placed AFTER generateDots()
showDivs(slideIndex);
```

```css
/* Just for illustration */
.active{outline:solid 1px red;}
```

```html
  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
 <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
  <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
   <h3>Slide 1</h3>
   <p>1. Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
  <div class="w3-display-bottomright w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
   <h3>Slide 2</h3>
   <p>2.Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
  <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
   <h3>Slide 3</h3>
   <p>3. Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
 <div id="js-slider-dots"></div>
 <button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi FZs, thank you for tip. I have no luck getting it to work. Console keeps showing me error "Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined at showDivs"

Comment: @VlastaPo Yes. That was because you called `showDivs` before `generateDots`. I've corrected my answer, take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

If you access the DOM from your `goToDiv` function, you can be sure that you are accessing the DOM after it has been updated with your `class="js-dot"` elements.

Something like this will give you the functionality you want.

```
function goToDiv(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('js-dot');
    for(var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      if (i == n - 1) {
        dots[i].classList.add('active');
      } else {
        dots[i].classList.remove('active');
      }
    }
}
```

Here it is in action:
https://jsbin.com/tekukebeye/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi Rowan, thank you, unfortunately it works only when I click the dots, but not when I use the arrows. So I moved the code to function showDivs() and now it switch classes for arrows too, but there is problem at the beginning/end, it will skip the last/first number and won't add the class. I updated JS Bin - https://jsbin.com/ketohatane/edit?html,css,js,console,output any idea pls?